# Set perdomain localstorage limit in Opera

Tags: html, opera, local-storage

If I run [this test](http://arty.name/localstorage.html) in Opera first time, then I get a popup, where I can set the storage size of this domain. But if I click cancel, then the next time there is no popup, the storage size will be the default.

So how to set the localStorage size per domain in Opera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the general quota limit, visit `opera:config#PersistentStorage|DomainQuotaForlocalStorage`.

To read/edit the **per domain quota** preference, open your profile directory (the location can be found via Help > "About Opera"), and edit `override.ini`<sup>(multi-user)</sup>. You can also open Opera's application folder, and edit `operaprefs.ini`.

The format is as follows:

```
[domain.tld]
Persistent Storage|Domain Quota For localStorage=<bytes>
Persistent Storage|Domain Quota Exceeded Handling For localStorage=0

[Overrides]
domain.tld
```

At the domain section, the first entry is the quota limit. The second entry is zero when you reject the request for quota expansion.

For more information, see [Opera's settings file explained#Persistent storage](http://www.opera.com/support/usingopera/operaini/#persistent_storage).

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately in the other browsers I can't set it per domain :S